# Can I reuse entries in from a former console?

Tags: texshop, auxiliary-files, typein, console

Hey I created a template document that asks the user for input to customize the document. The user inputs various entries into the TeXShop console. The LaTeX file uses those inputs throughout the document. Is there anyway to reuse entries from a previous console "session" so I don't have to retype everything if I made a mistake?

```
\typein[\color]{What's your favorite color? } % take user input
```

Above is an example of the function I'm using. Later in the text I reference this \typein by using the following syntax.

```
I like the color \color too!
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could save them to an auxiliary file and only ask for them if not available, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve. Please post a minimal, but compilable example.

Comment: Hi TeXnician. Thank you for the welcome! I edited the originial post to include an example of the code I'm running.

Comment: You should write the inputted values on a file, and then read it on startup and offer the values as a default option. Quite a complex thing. I would really use an auxiliary script written in a scripting language... interactivity with TeX was , in all fairness, one of the targets!

Comment: Rmano, are you saying to write a script in Python or another similiar language and have that script either use either the previous values or add new ones?

Comment: That's not a complete example anyone can compile. And is this really specific to TeXShop? I can't see why it would be.